# Events Website CMS/Framework Suggestions

Tags: frameworks, web, content-management-system

I'm planning to build a website that has the following in the first Phase

1. Events List
2. Events Management by admin
3. Register for events (buy tickets)
4. News List
5. Manage News
6. Support Multi-Language

In the next phase i would like the site to be a social networking site (considering elgg)

I want the website to be light and fast. I've tried Joomla/Drupal. They seem to be slow.

Any recommendations for a framework/CMS?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Textpattern](http://www.textpattern.org) for a CMS based website I am developing, and so far it seems like it can handle all of the CMS work I push at it while staying out of the way as far as code.  It has a bit of a learning curve like most CMS programs, but is pretty easy to pick up.  You'll still have to build out the functionality for events (look into the plugin [ZemEvents](http://code.google.com/p/zem-event/)), as Textpattern starts out with just the base install and you add on to it as needed.  You may need to handle E-commerce differently though, not sure if there are any plugins for Textpattern that could handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I, personally second LocalPCGuy’s recommendation since Textpattern is, in my eyes, the most underestimated CMS in the market. I especially love it for its simple XML-like templating tags.

Talking about easy templating you might also want to check out the Python based Django framework. This is, by far, the fastest framework/cms I ever came across.